# add .htaccess trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I'd like to put a trailing slash to my url with .htaccess just in these 3 cases:

1. The part after the last slash doesn't contain a `?` char
2. The part after the last slash doesn't contain a `.` char
3. The last url char is not a `/` char

I'd like to add those rules to my existing .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.* - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.* index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^((.*/)?[^/\.]+)$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/\?\.])$ http://example.com/$1/ [L]
```

Should do what you're looking for. Just add it right below `RewriteEngine On` in your existing file.

Comment: Question marks never appear in the rewriterule's path. Also he doesn't want any `.` after the last slash, so not not ending with a `.`.

Comment: Ah, right, Forgot about the query string bit and definitely spaced on the period. Looks like your answer should do the trick, though.